# iPhone App Update: Ignore backwards compatibility for iOS 3.X (iOS Deployment Target set to 4.0)

Tags: ios, xcode4, app-store, backwards-compatibility, ios3.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Supporting older iOS Versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011774/supporting-older-ios-versions)

I plan to drop support for iOS3.X in my next app update (change iOS Deployment Target from 3.0 to 4.0)

I was still targeting iOS 3.0, but can't test anymore my XCode project with older SDK (I can't launch the iOS3.0 simulator).

Do you know if it's possible? What happens to users with iOS 3.X, do they will see the update?
(I don't want user complaints)

Comment: Well, it looks like it's possible. I just tested to send an update targeting iOS 4.0 to an app previously targeting iOS 3.0, and it has been validated and "waiting for review". Now, I wonder what happens for customers with iOS 3.0

Comment: I assume your app has been approved and released now, any update on your experience?

Comment: I didn't took the risk, i asked a friend to test with his old iPod on iOS 3. It was working, so i just set back the target to 3.0. So I still have my question ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Users won't be able to install the new update as the minimum version will be updated on the App Store